# mysql export sql dump alphabatically,which cause foreign key constraints error during import

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, dump

I have 10 tables in my database(MySQL). two of them is given below

**tbl_state**

```
state_id    |int(10)  |UNSIGNED ZEROFILL  auto_increment 
state_name  |varchar(40)
```

**tbl_city**

```
city_id     |int(10)  |UNSIGNED ZEROFILL  auto_increment 
city_name   |varchar(40) |
state_code  |int(10)  | UNSIGNED ZEROFILL (FK reference with tbl_state.state_id)
```

**Foreign Key Constraint :**  **tbl_city.state_code** is references to **tbl_state.state_id** .

now my problem is

when I export all tables and import again then it gives

`foreign key constraint fails error....`
because when I export mysql dump, sql dump is generated in alphabetically ordered tables
and **tbl_city** comes before **tbl_state** in database.

Please suggest me how do I handle this scenario?

Is there any way that all tables comes in the order of foreign key references?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to disable foreign key checks at start of the dump, and then enable them after all the data is dumped:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0

... dump ...

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```

Comment: i can't do this bcoz i m xporting data from a machine and importing on another machine, and this will be done by a non technical person. and this process will b continue once in a day forever... 
suggest me some other idea

Comment: the technical person who is responsible for generating the dump should fix their script then. or use mysqldump which does this for you

Comment: can u tell me the link where i can find some script which export mysql into xml from one machine and import xml into mysql to another machine

Comment: You can use mysqldump with the --xml flag: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: And here's an article on importing the XML data back into a MySQL database: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing

Comment: listen to reko_t and create a script for the "dumb" end user to execute.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance if you use SQLYog. Use this property.[image]